# Java: How do I open a text file in test that is in src/main/resources?

Tags: java

my project struture looks like

```
project/
       src/main/
               java/ ...
               resources/
                         definitions.txt
               test/
                    CurrentTest.java
               resources/ ...
```

In my test I need to open the `definitions.txt`

I do

```
 @Test
 public void testReadDesiredDefinitions() throws PersistenceException, IOException {
        final Properties definitions = new Properties();
        definitions.load(new ResourceService("/").getStream("desiredDefinitions"));
        System.out.println(definitions);
 }
```

When I run this, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
```

How can I read this text file?

Thanks

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is `ResourceService`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "current directory" of unit tests is usually the project directory, so use this:

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/definitions.txt");
```

and load the properties from the file:

```
definitions.load(new FileInputStream(file));
```

If this doesn't work, or you want to check what the current directory is, just print out the path and it will be obvious what the current directory is:

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Note: If definitions.txt is going to be packaged within a JAR distribution, this won't work.

Comment: @Vulcan sure, but *my project structure looks like* to me is pretty clear that this is source

Comment: I'm not denying that, but not all end-users will have the entire source and its structure, such as in the case of a JAR distribution.

Comment: @Vulcan You've raised an interesting point, and I'm trying not to be deliberately defensive, but by definition unit tests (which this is) have the source code available. That is, this code will only ever run as raw source, never in jar.

Comment: Interesting point, I hadn't notice it was a unit test.  I would assume that the units being tested will often end up distributed in one form or another in another project.

Comment: @Vulcan Oh sure, but not *tested* in the distro. Unit tests are run as a post-compilation step and anything under `src/test` is excluded from the jar, so there's no danger in using a `File` (also, my little brain can understand files much easier than resource streams)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Class#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to easily create a stream to a resource file.

```
definitions.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/main/java/resources/definitions.txt"));
```

The location parameter should be the relative file path with regards to your project base (my guess was main).

Answer (score 0):

If your `resources` directory is a source folder, you can use `/resources/definitions.txt` as a correct path.

I don't know about `ResourceService` but this should work:

```
final Properties definitions = new Properties();
definitions.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/definitions.txt"))
```

Comment: This one is giving `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: How is your project being built? Following your project structure if you're generating in a folder named `classes` for example, then you will have your `resources` folder copied in it during build, and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

File file = new File("../src/main/resources/definitions.txt");